# Neo4j alternative relationships

Tags: neo4j

I'm just learning Neo4J, so apologies, I'm a novice.

I have created Nodes and Relationships for a simple process which repeats many times. In some instances a review node exists and in some cases it does not (see attached).

I want to know:

- If the review node does not exist then the relationship is between the decision node and the despatch node only.
- If the review node does exist then it must traverse that before the despatch.

Does that make sense?

[image: the nodes]

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a query that will return both kinds of paths, this should work:

```
MATCH p=(:Application)-->(dec:Decision)-[*0..1]->(x)-->(:Despatch)
WHERE x = dec OR 'Review' IN LABELS(x)
RETURN p;
```

The `variable length relationship` pattern `[*0..1]` will match relationship lengths of either 0 or 1. A "0-length relationship" just means that there is actually no relationship (and therefore the start node is the same as the end node).